# Custom Linux kernel build fails at loading initial ramdisk

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, boot, initramfs

I have been trying to build my own Linux kernel, but it keeps hanging after `Loading initial ramdisk...` I am currently using Arch linux, and have tried several different configs.

I tried both the 6.8-rc3 and the 6.7.4 releases, with the same error.

I am running an RX 570, a Ryzen 5 2600, and 16 gb of ram.

I tried a fully custom, slimmed down one. I tried a less optimized one, and I tried building one without changing any build settings (`make menuconfig` then saving and exiting without touching anything). I've also now tried compiling in the amdgpu and radeon drivers, to no avail.

Each time I built the kernel, my steps were this

```
wget https://git.kernel.org/torvalds/t/linux-6.8-rc3.tar.gz
tar xvf linux-6.8-rc3.tar.gz
cd linux-6.8-rc3
make menuconfig
make -j12 && sudo make modules_install -j12
sudo cp arch/x86/boot/bzImage /boot/vmlinuz-newlinux
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Then I would restart and select the advanced options and switch my kernel to the new one. Every outcome was the same. It would say:

```
Loading linux newlinux ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
_
```

Without the `quiet` option:

```
   Booting a command list

Loading Linux newlinux ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
_


            EFI stub: Loaded initrd from LINUX_EFI_INITRD_MEDIA_GUID device path
```

I gave it some time, almost 20 minutes, to see if that was the issue but still nothing. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you so much.

Comment: Remove the `quiet` kernel boot option, take a picture, add it to your question.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov done, thank you for reminding me

Comment: Have you compiled in a GPU driver for your system? Your system might have booted but there's nothing in the kernel to drive your GPU.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I just finished compiling in the amdgpu and radeon drivers, with the same output. `quiet` disabled returns the same output as before.

Comment: Please try booting without `quiet` and add this `efi=debug earlycon=efifb keep_bootcon`. If it still produces nothing, add `nomodeset` as well.

Comment: It produced 11 `__common_interrupt: x No irq handler for vector` then printed `systemd[1]: Freezing execution` with and without nomodeset

Comment: Is that really all? It must have shown a ton more. It could be that your config is missing some essential options for the kernel to work.

Comment: That is really all. Any ideas on how I could find those missing options? It really doesn't make sense to me how the defaults could be missing stuff.

Comment: Related: [initramfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_boot_process#initramfs), [Make initial RAM disk](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel/Traditional_compilation#Make_initial_RAM_disk).

Comment: One possible cause is an initramfs needing a decompressor that's not compiled into the kernel - check that your initramfs-tools is configured compatibly with your kernel config.